# How do I check if a file exists with * in python?

Tags: python, file, os.path

I'm trying to check if a file exists so I can read it. The kicker is I don't know what the number on the file is. Only one file should exist at a time, but the name updates as I write to the file (in another part of the code) so I don't know exactly what the number will be when this chunk of code executes.

```
N=0
if os.path.exists('*somefile.txt'): #if the file exists, read it
    print("found Nsomefile.txt")
    filename = '*somefile.txt'
    something=np.loadtxt(filename)
    N = int(filename.split('s')[0]) #save the N from the filename
else: #otherise, preallocate memory for something
    something = np.empty((x,y))  
print(N,"of some thing")
```

In my directory I can see the file there ('32somefile.txt') but the code still prints 
`0 of some thing`

Comment: If you want to use `*` in filename matching like the command shell of the OS, maybe consider importing the glob package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use glob rather than os functions here.

Glob also supports * characters, so it should do fine for your use case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use glob() from pathlib.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I forgot about glob. (I use it in another part of my code (*facepalm*)). It now looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
N=0
if glob('*somefile.txt'): #if the file exists, read it
    print("found Nsomefile.txt")
    filename = glob('*somefile.txt')[0]
    something=np.loadtxt(filename)
    N = int(filename.split('s')[0]) #save the N from the filename
else: #otherise, preallocate memory for something
    something = np.empty((x,y))  
print(N,"of some thing")
```

which outputs

```
found Nsomefile.txt
32 of some thing
```